# How to run appium automaion script from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, appium

I have installed appium on my machine, it works fine and generates code.
But i dont know how to run it from Xcode, rather how to run java code from Xcode, I have tried makefile but it gives problem..
Can anybody tell me how to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looking for a solution, probably a bash script is the right way **Loading**